# Box Layout in IOS 6/7?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a way to achieve a menu like this using built in ios containers / layouts:

[image: http://zetcode.com/img/gui/javaswing/rigidarea.png]

Assuming all my ui components are made programmatically. I have 5 buttons and I want them centered. I can do it myself but was wondering what sort of layout options ios offers.

Comment: Do you want the flexibility to add more buttons vertically?

Comment: If the question is simply "Is there a way..." then the answer is "Yes. Yes there is."

Comment: @Aaron Nope, just need exactly what the image shows

Comment: @Milo Presumably you don't mean *exactly* what the image shows, as iOS buttons normally don't look like those, and the window controls don't make any sense in an iOS context...

Comment: Do you want to support different device orientations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can do that. The best solution would be to use the auto layout system, where you set constraints on the various subviews and the layout system attempts to satisfy those constraints. For example, you can specify that the four buttons should be laid out vertically with standard size and spacing (or dimensions that you specify). You can specify that they should be centered horizontally, and that the space above and below should be equal.

Some constraints can be specified visually in Xcode's .xib/storyboard editor. More complex constraints can be created in code. (People often get the idea that auto layout means no code, but that's not always true.)

Read more about auto layout in Apple's [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 1):

A `UIActionSheet` is an example of this.

[image]

Internally, there is a table and each row represents a button. You layout each cell, and the table view layouts the cells.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible using Auto Layout. You would probably want to group the buttons into a containing UIView, pin it's height and width, then vertically and horizontally center it. The buttons, once in the container, could either be laid out by hard coding their X,Ys, or otherwise by adding constraints to the buttons that would pin each of the spaces between the buttons, the space between the top button and the top, then the bottom button and the bottom.

When using Auto Layout and viewing your storyboard check out the Editor menu. Specifically the Editor > Align and Editor > Pin menu options.